# I have 12 phrase recovery code for bitcoin wallet

Tags: blockchain, wallet, passphrase

I have 12 phrase recovery code for bitcoin wallet and I use it for purchased shop and for every deposit generate a new wallet now I restore my 12 word to blockchain and electrum and exodus and … but just show me first transaction and I can get access to my other wallet and balance I appreciate you if can help me

Comment: It’s unclear what your question is. Can you edit it to include information about what you’d like to do, what you tried doing, and what happened when you did it?